# jQAssistant scan missing value for retrofit2.http.GET

Tags: neo4j, cypher, jqassistant

After scanning my project with cli-jqassistant-commandline-neo4jv4-2.1.0.jar and executing a cypher to get the value of @GET(value = "/test/two"), no record is returned.

I tried the following:
I have the following interface in my project

```
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.Path;

interface TestService
{
    @POST(value = "/test/one")
    Call<ResponseBody> executeQuery(@Path("test") String test);

    @GET(value = "/test/two")
    Call<ResponseBody> getQuery(@Path("test") String test);

}
```

I'm running cli-jqassistant-commandline-neo4jv4-2.1.0.jar to scan the project
When I execute the following cypher:

```
MATCH (client:Interface)-[:DECLARES]->(m:Method)
MATCH (m)-[:ANNOTATED_BY]->(ann:Annotation)-[:HAS]->(:Value{name:"value"})-[:CONTAINS]->(url:Value)
return url.value
```

OR

```
MATCH (client:Interface)-[:DECLARES]->(m:Method)
MATCH (m)-[:ANNOTATED_BY]->(ann:Annotation)-[:OF_TYPE]->(:Type{name:"GET"})
MATCH (ann)-[:HAS]->(:Value{name:"value"})-[:CONTAINS]->(url:Value)
return m
```

I don't get anything as result. I expect to get both values value = "/test/one" and value = "/test/two"

if I execute the following cypher:

```
MATCH (client:Interface)-[:DECLARES]->(m:Method)
return m
```

I get the following result:

```
{
  "identity": 12598,
  "labels": [
    "Java",
    "ByteCode",
    "Method",
    "Member"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "visibility": "public",
    "signature": "retrofit2.Call executeQuery(java.lang.String)",
    "name": "executeQuery",
    "abstract": true,
    "cyclomaticComplexity": 0
  },
  "elementId": "12598"
},
{
  "identity": 12611,
  "labels": [
    "Java",
    "ByteCode",
    "Method",
    "Member"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "visibility": "public",
    "signature": "retrofit2.Call getQuery(java.lang.String)",
    "name": "getQuery",
    "abstract": true,
    "cyclomaticComplexity": 0
  },
  "elementId": "12611"
}
```

The methods are there, but the values are missing.
Is this a problem of the cypher or it is not scanning and recording these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query for getting the value for the GET annotation should be like this:

```
MATCH
  (client:Interface)-[:DECLARES]->(m:Method),
  (m)-[:ANNOTATED_BY]->(ann)-[:OF_TYPE]->(:Type{fqn: "retrofit2.http.GET"}),
  (ann)-[:HAS]->(v:Value:Primitive{name:"value"})
RETURN
  client.fqn, m.signature, v.value
```

Notice the fully qualified name for the annotation which is needed (because the annotation class itself is not scanned and therefore the property `name` is not available, only `fqn`)